# How to debug ionic 2 native

Tags: debugging, ionic2

What is the best way to debug ionic 2 native features like the camera?

My app keeps crashing after i give permission to use the camera on my android device. Google chrome dev tools won't work in my case.

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- The disadvantages of Ionic framework is hard to debug when call native plugin.
- I have suggestion. Should you put breakpoint 'debugger' or "console.log()" before and after your function call Camera ?. And open chrome with url : 'chrome://inspect/#devices' to check what's happen ?

cheer!

Answer (score 0):

Chrome did leave me with an error:

file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.ionic.starter/cache/.Pic.jpg exposed beyond app through ClipData.Item.getUri()

I do want to know how to fix this but i will start a diffrend question

Answer (score -1):

I think that you could use  chrome for debugging , steps you will follow :

1. connect your pc with your android or IOS device
2. open chrome and right click , then choose inspect
3. from the top bar choose more tools then choose remote devices
4. then click on your connected device in devices settings
5. write the command ionic cordova run android --device in your terminal to run your app.
6. click inspect your device on chrome